# Extracting certain part of a string using strtok

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to extract a part of the string by using `strtok()`, but I am unable to get complete output.

For input:

```
string = '3_5_2_spd_20kmin_corrected_1_20190326.txt';
```

Output:

```
>> strtok(string)    
ans =    
    '3_5_2_spd_20kmin_corrected_1_20190326.txt'

>> strtok(string,'.txt')    
ans =    
    '3_5_2_spd_20kmin_correc'

>> strtok(string,'0326')    
ans =    
    '_5_'

>> strtok(string,'2019')    
ans =    
    '3_5_'

>> strtok(string,'.txt')    
ans =    
    '3_5_2_spd_20kmin_correc'
```

I expect the output `3_5_2_spd_20kmin_corrected_1_20190326`, but the actual output was `3_5_2_spd_20kmin_correc`. Why is that and how can I get the correct output?

Answer (score 2):

[`strtok`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html) treats every character inside the second input argument as a separate delimiter.

For example, when calling:
`strtok("3_5_2_spd_20kmin_corrected_1_20190326.txt",'.txt')`
Matlab sees as separate delimiters the `.`,`t`,`x` and therefore splits your input at the first `t` it encounters and gives back the result `3_5_2_spd_20kmin_correc`.

In your other example using `'2019'`, again `'2019'` is not a single delimiter but delimiterS, in the sense that the actual delimiters used are all `'2'`,`'0'`,`'1'`,`'9'`. Therefore the first delimiter encountered in the string (left to right) is `'2'`, right after `'3_5_'`. That's why it returns `'3_5_'`.

To achieve your expected output, I think you would be better off using
[`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html)
instead:

```
result = strsplit(string,".txt");
result{1}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. If it did solve your problem fully, [consider accepting it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (click the tick besides the answer)

Comment: But I still don’t get why I set,for example,’2019’ as the delimiter, it turns out only ‘3_5_’? It wouldn’t be restricted by the repetitive letter right?

Comment: The key is that '2019' is not a single delimiter but delimiterS, in the sense that the actual delimiters used are '2','0','1','9'. At your input, the first delimiter it encounters in the string (left to right) is '2', right after '3_5_'. That's why it returns '3_5_'.

Comment: Problems are finally solved! Perhaps matlab should add more details in the example of help documentation.

Answer (score 1):

extractBefore does what you're looking to do:

```
>> string = '3_5_2_spd_20kmin_corrected_1_20190326.txt';
>> extractBefore(string,'.txt')

ans =

    '3_5_2_spd_20kmin_corrected_1_20190326'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your strings are file names/paths, and your goal is to extract the file name without extension, the best option would be to use [`fileparts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html), like so:

```
>> str = '3_5_2_spd_20kmin_corrected_1_20190326.txt';
>> [~, name] = fileparts(str)

name =

    '3_5_2_spd_20kmin_corrected_1_20190326'
```

Comment: That would be better!